# How to upgrade a harddisk in Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have Macbook pro 
13inch, retina display 
with i5 processor and 
8GB RAM with 128 GB SSD, earlier 2015 model. 
With OSx Yosemite 14.1.0
I need to upgrade SSD with 750 GB.
I have following questions on this.

1. Is it a good Idea to upgrade it in Macbook? I have done several suck operations in Linux and windows machine, but haveing no Idea what it will impact on OSx re-installation and bootcamp.
2. Its Obivous that SSD will updgrade the performace, but is it significant improves the performace (FYI- I have heavy code compilation work).
3. What are all backups and percautions one must take while upgrading the SDD on macbook?(Newbie to mac world.)
4. Can I use the external SDD as a different partition for my MacBook?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What year is the MBP? After the 2012 version, the main SSD is soldered to the mobo, meaning any additional SSD would have have to be an 'additional' rather than 'instead of'.

Comment: @Ian, your statement "_After the 2012 version, the main SSD is soldered to the mobo, meaning any additional SSD would have have to be an 'additional' rather than 'instead of'_" is not correct!

Comment: its 2015, are you suggesting that, replacement is not possible and I can use it as external SSD?

Comment: @Nilesh Pardesi, We need the exact model information to provide an answer. Please edit your question and provide the exact model information, e.g. MacBook Pro Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013, Model Identifier MacBookPro11,1

Comment: Yep, apologies. I thought that this was so; after 2012 a normal SSD drive won't fit, will need to buy a special one. https://9to5mac.com/2015/02/24/upgrade-ssd-macbook-air-retina-macbook-pro/

Comment: Ask Different works much better if you only ask one question per question and don't be surprised if your post is edited down to one question or closed as to broad. Anyway, have a look at [Solid State Drive Upgrades MacBook Pro with Retina Display 13" & 15" Late 2013, 2014, and 2015](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015) for an SSD upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I would suggest using an external drive? Why? For the simple reason that upgrading the MBP SSD is expensive! It's not your standard SATA drive. A new 1TB SSD for that computer will run you ~$650 (based on OWC prices).

2)Your SSD Read/Write speed should already be around 400-500MBps. A new SSD's performance would probably not be noticeable. It is almost certainly not worth paying the $650 for just the speed boost.

3) I would suggest at least one (possibly two) backups. Note that if you buy your new SSD from OWC or if you get the OWC Envoy, you can plug your old SSD into your computer via USB, so having an extra (second) backup is less important if you take this route.

4) I'm not sure exactly what you mean here. You can use an external SSD as either a storage drive or a boot drive or both, but boot times from an external drive might be slower than from an internal drive.

Please comment with any questions or if you see any mistakes in my answer.

Comment: I am looking for the cost effective solution, ofcourse it looks like better option to go for a backup data drives instead of upgrading the SSD's. My intension is, if it has a significant improvement in the performance then only I must go for the upgradation of SSD. if its not significant then, I would like to use the external HDD as a backup as you have suggested.

Comment: Yes, @NileshPardesi. I'd suggest getting an external drive. Whether you get an external SSD or HDD is up to you, but because the SSD in the MBP (special type of SSD) is so expensive, I wouldn't upgrade it

Comment: You said, "_A new 1TB SSD for that computer will run you ~$800-$900 (based on eBay prices)._", well eBay is not the only place and in this case I'd probably only get it from OWC considering the form factor and it's $598.00 for 1 TB from OWC. For a little bit more you get the Kit which includes tools & transfer enclosure for $647.99. That's a big difference between ~$800-$900!

Comment: @user3439894 thank you! I'll update my answer to reflect that